# Mybatis - something like @PostConstruct

Tags: java, mybatis

Is it possible to invoke some method after creating object by MyBatis?  My aim is to set additional parameter based on values (presence or absence (`null`)  set by MyBatis.

From my research, it implies that MyBatis always invoke no-parameter constructor. In case lack of such constructor it try to invoke constructor with parameters matching to returned result from database.

I think that only way is creating custom TypeHandler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TypeHandler scope is 1 column and does not know about mapping.

I would rather use ResultHandler: they are called after each result row is mapped.

The context points on the mapped result object, then you can do anything you want on the object.

There is a limit if the result map uses collection (because multiple result row may match single object).

It is called this way: `session.list("statement", params, resultHandler);`
This overrides the default resultHandler then If you need a list of results, then the resultHandler implementation will have to add the objects to the list.

If you are using mapper interfaces, which seems to be the case with Spring-boot (*mappers marked with the @Mapper annotation*), then just pass the result handler as argument, the mapper method will look like `void myStatement(Object param, ResultHandler resultHandler);`

Comment: `session.list("statement", params, resultHandler);` - how to use it in `mybatis-spring-boot` ?

Comment: can we talk on chat ? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134576/java ? about mybatis - I have some questions